# css background-image won't display in IE or Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use background-image:url('path/to/image.png'); to place a background image in a div by ID:

```
#logo_block > #main_logo {
background-image: url("img/JaxonsBlack.png");
width:450px;
height:auto; }
```

and the html is as such:

```
    <div id="logo_block">
        <!-- This will remain static. -->
        <div id="main_logo">
            <!--<img id ="logo" src="img/JaxonsBlack.png" width="400" />-->
        </div>

        <!-- This div will be dynamically populated in the future
        it resides immediately under the logo image-->
        <div id="sub_title">
            <h3>sample</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ok, so no matter what I try, I can't get this to work.

1. its not a pathing issue. The img tag in the html below works fine when its not commented out. I can apply the very same CSS to the body and it works fine as well.
2. Selectors. Its not those. I look at Chrome's developer tools and the style is being applied to the div appropriately. I have also removed the div from the parent div and used simply #main_logo as the selector, tried a class, etc etc etc.
3. Height. its not the height style. I've seen that mentioned, and with or without height, width, etc, it still doesn't work.

I can't seem to find any info on this issue anywhere. My syntax is correct as far as I can see, and multiple sites support that. This doesn't work in Chrome or *shudder* IE. My FF install is currently broken (again) so I haven't tried it there. I somehow doubt it'll be any different, but if it doesn't work in Chrome or IE, I still need to figure this out.

I'm at my wit's end on this. It simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It **is** the height style. `height` is set to `auto`, so it'll only be as tall as it needs to be to show all the content, but there's no content in there, hence it's 0px tall.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z632P/ - change the `height` to `auto` then back to `100px`.

Comment: I agree with Joe - it has to be height. As a test, try applying a background-color to your #main-logo div, and then mess with the height.

Comment: Wow. So apparently during my hairpulling all afternoon, I failed to hit that one combination. Without a width AND height specified, it doesn't work at all. I'm such a n00b sometimes. :P

Thank you, this fixes it.

Comment: Err... no comment :P But yeah, if an element is empty (nothing in it with dimensions) it will close up to be 0px by 0px, so you have to force it a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
height: 100%;
```

instead.

If it's working in other browsers, this should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your style defined in a separate css file? If so, the path should be relative to the css file, not to the html file. So if you have your css file in /styles/blah.css and you have the url img/JaxonsBlack.png, it will look for it in /styles/img/JaxonsBlack.png. If this is the case you can fix it by changing it to /img/JaxonsBlack.png. As others have mentioned, the div will not have a vertical height unless it has content, or you define one.